# Hardware device not detecting on Windows 7 - detects only on reboot

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I am trying to connect a data connector (USB like hardware device to connect internet), but it not detecting the device, I have installed the device driver software came with the device.

Issues is that its detecting only on Computer reboot, while device should already be connected.

If I unplug the device and connect again, its not detecting hardware.

So any time I need to connect to the device, I need to shut down my system, connect device and start it again.

I have tried to uninstall Device driver and reinstalled it but the problem is not yet resolved. I am using Windows 7 OS.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of plug and play messages when attaching the device?  Any errors in the event log?  Is there a USB hub involved? (If so, bypass the hub and attach device directly to USB port on the PC)

Comment: I am neither getting plug and play messages nor any errors in the event logs. It's connected directly to USB port, there is no USB hub involved.
Its detecting only on Computer reboot, while device should already be connected.
So any time i need to connect with device, i need to shutdown my system, connect device and start it again.

Comment: What is the device?

Comment: The device is "Huawei ec1262" to connect broadband internet.

Comment: is there any solution?